# How to delete row from SQLiteDatabase?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a todo app which shows on the mainscreen a list of tasks with `ListView`. I'm trying to delete a task by clicking on the done button.

But the app is deleting it by the lowest id instead of deleting the task that i tried to delete.

```
 public void onDoneButtonClick(View view) {

    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    int columnId = cursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID);
    int id = cursor.getInt(columnId);
    Log.d("id", Float.toString(id));

   String sql = String.format("DELETE FROM %s WHERE %s = %d",
            TaskContract.TABLE,
            TaskContract.Columns._ID,
            id);

    helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivity.this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    sqlDB.execSQL(sql);
    updateUI();

    Log.d("delete", sql);


 }
```

Can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: @MD when I click on the done button, then it's not deleting that particular task but the first task in the row.

Comment: Are you tried delete method? http://tinyurl.com/ngv2v3n

Comment: `sqlDB.delete(TaskContract.TABLE, TaskContract.Columns._ID + "=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});`

Comment: @krystian71115 yes but I failed on it. I'm just new and this is a school project. I can delete it by task but not by ID.

Comment: Can you paste the result of String.format? I mean about `sql` variable.

Comment: @krystian71115 /id﹕ 15.0 (this is what i get whet i delete something, and that number changes)

Comment: Are you tried code from my answer?

Comment: @krystian71115 yes but I get this error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference

Comment: @krystian71115 it deletes the task, but still not the one i click on. It gets the first one :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delete method in SQLiteDatabase:

http://tinyurl.com/ngv2v3n

Edit:

```
// you must do it after opening database
helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivity.this);
SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getWritableDatabase();

sqlDB.delete(
             TaskContract.TABLE,  // table
             TaskContract.Columns._ID + "=?", // where clause
             new String[]{Integer.toString(id)} // where args
            );
```

Comment: sorry, it still deletes the first in one in the row :(

Comment: @SelinAksu Maybe the problem is not with SQLDatabase. Are you sure the correct listener is called and the cursor is at valid position?

Comment: @SelinAksu Maybe you are not moving to the correct position. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToPosition(int)

Comment: Thanks for the info, i'm going to try it :))